# Unexplained job dependency error and rerun trigger

Tags: snakemake

I am getting some behavior I cannot understand, and might be difficult for me to communicate.
I have a pipeline that after preprocessing classifies some metagenomic reads in one rule, then another rule calculates transcripts per million for the classification. Weird thing is, The classification rule runs fine, and then the normalization rule give me erratic behavior. In the beginning it run fine for a test sample (I am quite sure I did not change any relevant code), then when I tried analyzing all the samples it 1. created a cyclic dependency error in a completely different rule, 2. for a reason I cannot understand messed up the wildcards, so that the input files the workflow was expecting became nonsensical, and of course were missing (it added part of the filename of its own output, to the input filenames of the whole pipeline). After that I decided to run the whole workflow up to, but not including the normalization step for all samples, which went fine, and as soon as I tried to include the normalization step it is triggering a rerun of all the steps, this time without producing the filename related error. I am providing the code of the two rules I have mentioned and please let me know if anything else would be useful to troubleshoot this. Many thanks.

```py
rule resfinder:
    input:
        readF = output_dir + "rqcfilter2/deinterleaved/{sample}/{sample}_1.anqdpht.fastq.gz",
        readR = output_dir + "rqcfilter2/deinterleaved/{sample}/{sample}_2.anqdpht.fastq.gz",
    output:
        res_temp = temp(output_dir + "resfinder/{sample}/resfinder_kma/{sample}_all.unsorted.res"),
        res = output_dir + "resfinder/{sample}/resfinder_kma/{sample}_all.res",
    log:
        output_dir + "logs/resfinder/{sample}.log",
    params:
        out_dir = output_dir + "resfinder/{sample}/",
        db_res = db_dir + config["resfinder"]["db_res"],
    conda:
        "envs/resfinder.yaml",
    shell:
        """
        # Checks if databases have been built and builds them otherwise
        if [ ! -e {params.db_res}/all.comp.b ]
        then
            {params.db_res}/INSTALL.py
        fi

        # Runs resfinder
        run_resfinder.py -ifq {input.readF} {input.readR} -o {params.out_dir} --acquired -db_res {params.db_res}

        # Create a summary results file and sorts it
        array=( {params.out_dir}resfinder_kma/*.res )
        {{ cat ${{array[@]:0:1}}; grep -vh "^#" ${{array[@]:1}}; }} > {output.res_temp}
        (head -n 1 {output.res_temp} && tail -n +2 {output.res_temp}  | sort -nr -k2 -t$'\t') > {output.res}
        """

# Filters Resfinder results based on 90% identity, 60% coverage, calculates Transcripts per Million, and sorts based on that
rule filter_and_normalize_resfinder:
    input:
        res_sorted = output_dir + "resfinder/{sample}/resfinder_kma/{sample}_all.res",
        ref = output_dir + "multiqc/clean/multiqc_report_data/multiqc_fastqc.txt",
    output:
        res = output_dir + "resfinder/{sample}_filtered_normalized.res",
    run:
        # Reads files
        ref = pd.read_csv(input.ref, sep="\t")
        res = pd.read_csv(input.res_sorted, sep="\t")
        
        # Filter results using Strict criteria of 60% coverage and 90% identity
        res = res.query('Template_Coverage >= 60 & Query_Identity >= 90')

        # Calculates TPM by first normalizing for gene length, and then by total sequencing depth (not just ARG reads)
        new_res = res
        new_res['TPM'] = new_res['Depth'] / (new_res['Template_length']/1000) * ((ref.query('Sample == "'+wildcards.sample+'_1.anqdpht"').iat[0, 4])/1000000)

        # Saves new results
        new_res.to_csv(output.res, sep="\t", index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful to see the errors you get, this is a wild guess... You may need to constrain your wildcards to prevent snakemake from matching too much. Assuming the values that `{sample}` can take are in list `SAMPLES`, add this before the first rule of the pipeline:

```
SAMPLES = ['sample1', 'sample2', etc. etc.]

wildcard_constraints:
    sample = '|'.join([re.escape(x) for x in SAMPLES]),

rule all:
    etc. etc.
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I have been trying to make sense of it between other tasks.

The problem now seems to be the unexpected rerun triggers. When I change something in a rule that is used as input for a single rule, it triggers a rerun of the whole pipeline. I do not know what would be useful to show you in this case. I have checked that the output of the rule I am changing is not used somewhere else, and I have also checked that the one downstream rule is not connected to other rules either. And all the wildcard in the job that fails seem to be working fine.